# What is the best way to match id's against a regular expression in Hpricot?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

Using apricot, it is pretty easy to see how I can extract all elements with a given id or class using a CSS Selector. Is it possible to extract elements from a document based on whether some attribute of those elements matches against some regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean do something like:

```
doc.search("//div[@id=/regex/]")
```

then I don't think it can be done. The alternative is to find all elements and then iterate through the results deleting those that don't match a regex.

```
result = doc.search("//div")
result.delete_if (|x| x.to_s !~ /regex/)
```

There are lots of alternative approaches. This thread has two other suggestions: [Hpricot and Regular Expression](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/230281?230177-231634).

Note, depending on exactly what it is you are trying to match you may be able to use the "Supported, but different" syntaxes available on the [Hpricot Wiki](http://wiki.github.com/hpricot/hpricot/supported-css-selectors), e.g:

```
E[@foo$=“bar”]
```

> Matches an E element whose “foo”
>   attribute value ends exactly with the
>   string “bar”